# Change Sublime Text Bracket/Indent Rules

Tags: css, editor, sublimetext2

I'm trying to figure out how to change Sublime Texts auto bracket rules for css.

I get this by default:

```
.class {
    #CURSOR
}
```

I would like to have this:

```
.class {
    #CURSOR}
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: The first way is the correct/traditional placement for the closing bracket. I've no idea how you would change that in Sublime or indeed why you would want to as it may effect the readability of the css for yourself and for potential future developers of your css file.

Comment: as @BillyMoat said, why would you want that?

Comment: Thanks for the... answer? Sass compiles this way. And I kinda like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this shortcut to your `Key Bindings - User`:

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\n\t"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\{$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\}", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.css" }
    ]
}
```

to modify <kbd>enter</kbd> key behaviour with `css` files.

Or you can use a Snippet. `Tools/New Snippet...`:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
{
    ${1}}
]]>
    </content>
</snippet>
```

Save it as `Packages/User/CSSBrackets.sublime-snippet`.

Then, add a shortcut in your `Key Bindings - User` to trigger it when pressing <kbd>{</kbd> in `css` files:

```
{ "keys": ["{"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"name": "Packages/User/CSSBrackets.sublime-snippet"}, 
"context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.css" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Bummed. Tried both of these with no success. And I missing something? I tried restarting ST, still no luck. ;(

Comment: This bindings are meant to be triggered only with CSS (context is `{ "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.css" }`). Are you editing CSS or something else?

Comment: Ah, .scss. Guess that might be the issue. just change to source.scss?

Comment: fixed is by adding `{ "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.scss" }`

Comment: Wasn't working for me with LESS until I changed it to 'source.less'.